# AJAX optimization - instead of checking every 2 ms?

Tags: ajax, optimization, polling, long-polling

Heylo guys

i am writing an experimental AJAX page that checks the data of a txt file every 2 ms and if there is a change, post the change to the page

problem is that this is very inefficient bandwidth wise and computation-wise. Is there another way to do this? I have heard of websockets (not familiar though)

thx!

Comment: Why 2ms? Sounds like overkill.

Comment: First you have to measure how long it takes to send the AJAX request, get the response, and compare the response text to the existing text - this process certainly takes longer than 2ms. (You can use `console.time` and `console.timeEnd` to measure this (in Chrome).)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use COMET

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29

Answer (score 1):

AJAX Push (Comet server) is exactly what you need. This is a very powerful tookit/engine: http://www.ape-project.org/

Answer (score 1):

Instead of comparing the data, you could only compare the file size/last modified date on your server side script and return a 0/1 depending on if it didn't change or did.

Apart from that you'll have to tell us more about which language you're using on the server for us to be able to tell you what to do. You can use [Long Polling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology) or [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29), but it really depends on your server side language how good those would be. With PHP for example, I've found these to not be possible unless I installed stuff on the server, which in shared hosting for example is not possible.

Comment: the server is ASP and has no additional technology installed on it. not exactly sure of the type of server (linux, windows...)

Answer (score 1):

Checking a text file 500 times per second is a bad idea, IMHO.

My suggestion is to have your server-side script check the modified date and "push" a notification to your AJAX listeners.  Node.js and Faye would be good for this.

A good screencast on Node can be found here ($12):

http://peepcode.com/products/nodejs-i

That screencast also covers Faye (http://faye.jcoglan.com/node.html).  Faye simplifies the whole Comet/polling process.